# SQL Query determining oldest message with additional criteria

Tags: sql-server

I've got a rather complicated query that sounds easy on the surface but is proving more trouble than I expected.

I have a table named `inboundMessages` which acts as a sort of FIFO queue, but with a twist. I need to get the oldest non-processed message (status `0`) that does not have a status of `1` or `3`.

**Example:**

```
Id     messageID     Status     ReceivedDateTime
-------------------------------------------------------
112    1234          1          2018-08-07 14:52:48.657
113    1234          3          2018-08-08 14:52:48.657
114    1234          0          2018-08-07 14:52:48.657
119    1235          2          2018-08-07 16:05:10.870
120    1235          0          2018-08-08 10:37:09.980
121    1237          0          2018-08-09 05:43:08.824
```

**Wanted Results**

```
120    1235          0          2018-08-08 10:37:09.980
```

**Statuses**

```
ID       Status
0        Not picked up, not processed
1        Picked up - not processed 
2        Processed Successfully 
3        Error during processing 
4        Errored - Refiled
5        Errored - Ignored, unresolvable.
```

ID 114  would not be valid because other rows have the same messageID and a status of 1 or 3 meaning those will
need to be resolved before it could be picked up.

ID 121 is almost valid because there are no earlier messages with the MessageID of 1237, but it's not the oldest.

ID 120 is valid because it has an earlier message of 1235, but it's status is 2, meaning it filed successfully.

I've tried using a query using a status and trying to use a "having" clause, but it doesn't seem to be right as I'm not getting any results.

My query:

```
SELECT [Id]
       ,[MessageID]
      ,[Status]
      ,[ReceivedDateTime]
       ,COUNT(case when  status = 2  or status = 3  then 1 END) as  'Count'
  FROM inboundMessages

 group by [Id]
       ,[MessageID]
      ,[Status]
      ,[ReceivedDateTime]

  having Status=0 and COUNT(case when  status = 1 or status = 3 then 1 END) >=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a two step process, first get the rows that are valid (Status=0) and then get the first one that does not have another row in the set with a 1 or 3

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(Id int, messageID int, Status int,ReceivedDateTime datetime)

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(112,1234,1,'2018-08-07 14:52:48.657')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(113,1234,3,'2018-08-08 14:52:48.657')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(114,1234,0,'2018-08-07 14:52:48.657')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(119,1235,2,'2018-08-07 16:05:10.870')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(120,1235,0,'2018-08-08 10:37:09.980')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(121,1237,0,'2018-08-09 05:43:08.824')

;WITH CTE as 
    (
    SELECT Id,messageID,ReceivedDateTime from #tmp t1 where Status = 0
    )
SELECT  TOP 1 * from CTE
 where messageID not in(select messageID from #tmp where Status in (1,3))
 ORDER BY ReceivedDateTime
```

Comment: This is what we ended up going with upon consulting with co-workers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.

```
select 
--select only 1 record
top 1 *
--from your base table
from inboundMessages
--where the messageID has a status of 0 and 2
where messageID in (select messageID from inboundMessages where Status not in (1,3)  group by messageID having count(distinct Status) > 1)
--of those messageID's that meet the where criteria, bring back only the row with Status = 0
and Status = 0
--make sure it's the oldest record (to only get one, and the correct one)
order by ReveivedDateTime desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I attempted to run that, and I'm seeing a message of Column 'inboundMessages.MessageID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. I added a GROUP BY to the query, and am receiving now no results.

Comment: Excellent. Would you mind explaining how it works? I think I understand, I just want to fully make sure. Please take your time, now that I have something working  I can move forward, but If I need to explain it to others it would be appreciated.

Comment: added some comments @RJohnson let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: Thanks, @scsimon. I did some testing, and it seems that the query is ignoring those rows that only have one entry. I removed the top 1 * to be able to see the entire "list" of valid entries, and I'm only getting entry with ID 120. I also adjusted it's received date to after 121's date, and it still only returns 120. I'd expect to see 121 in that instance. Any suggestions?

Comment: But you said 121 was *almost valid* and didn’t include it in the expected results. Why should it be included now?

Comment: can you elaborate @RJohnson? My answer matches your expected results.

Comment: When I change 121 to have a received date of _before_ 120, I still receive 120 as the result. I would also expect when removing the top 1 (to just be select *...) that I would see two results as both are "valid", even without changing the date.

Comment: Incorrect. Changing the DateTime for 121 would not change this because 121 only has a single status of 0. Your description is wrong if you expect this to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can may help you.

```
SELECT
    Id, messageID, Status, ReceivedDateTime
FROM inboundMessages
WHERE messageID IN (
    SELECT
        messageID
    FROM inboundMessages
    WHERE Status NOT IN (1, 3)
    GROUP BY messageID
    HAVING COUNT(messageID) > 1
)
    AND Status = 0 
GROUP BY Id, messageID, Status, ReceivedDateTime
```